# FragmentTransaction.repalce with customized fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-support-library

I am trying to build an activity that employs a `ViewPager` (`FragmentPagerAdapter`). Inside the `ViewPager`, I would like to open fragments programmatically. I know this can easily be achieved using `FragmentTransaction.replace(int, Fragment)`, but I would like to use my own Fragment object. I know you can do that if you use `android.app.FragmentTransaction.replace`, but unfortunately from what I have found so far you can only use the support package (`android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction`) because the `ViewPager` originates in the support package.

Are there any workarounds/alternatives? Is there something like `ViewPager` in Android.view or something? Or anything that can produce tabs at the top and have it swipeable like the `ViewPager` (`FragmentPagerAdapter`)?

Really I guess the question I'm asking is if there is a way to use my own Fragment (e.g. `MyFragment extends Fragment` and use "MyFragment" as a fragment in a `ViewPager`).

Thanks for the help in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the support library and use the `FragmentActivity` class along with the support `Fragment` class `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` to use fragments in your viewpager

you will have to change all your fragments you want to use in the viewpager over to the support fragment

Comment: And how would one go about converting all of my fragments to support fragments?

Comment: oh nono I think I was not clear enough about my problem. I of course acknowledge the difference between the support fragment and regular fragment when doing the fragment transaction and what not. The real problem is (what I think you're kind of getting at) that it only accepts the support fragment, and not any extension of it. Here is the verbatim error: The method replace(int, Fragment) in the type FragmentTransaction is not applicable for the arguments (int, MyFragment). And yes MyFragment only uses the support fragment.

Comment: Yes you need to use support everything meaning you need to use `getSupportFragmentManager()` too